# Tagging part of data as a hyperlink, iText

Tags: java, itext

I have a paragraph(*coming from database table*) which may contain a web address (*e.g www.google.com*). In the generated *PDF* document this automatically behaves as if its a hyperlink (hand cursor with clickable action).
Is there a way to tag it as a hyperlink?

I have previously created and tagged as hyperlink using the following code:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk("www.google.com", font);
PdfAction action = new PdfAction("www.google.com");

PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(writer,new Rectangle(0, 0), PdfName.HIGHLIGHT, action);
annotation.put(PdfName.CONTENTS,new PdfString("www.google.com"));
annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(0,PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED));
c.setAnnotation(annotation);
```

But this was for a static text.
The paragraph in question may contain a link or may not contain a link.
How to get across this situation?

Comment: Just for reference, the "text automatically converted to a hyperlink" is actually a feature of Adobe's products and isn't guaranteed to be a feature of other products. You can disable it by going to Edit > Preferences > General > "Create links from URLs". According to [this blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2013/03/removing-hyperlinks-from-a-pdf-and-featuregotcha/), these automatic links will still be created even if you manually create an annotation, however they will effectively be z-indexed behind it your annotation and won't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the paragraph text from the database, I assume you have a `String`. You can simply check if that `String` contains a URL, e.g. using basic [String matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html), depending on how thorough it needs to be.

Once you have determined which part of the `String` is the URL, you can split it in 3 parts: *Before*, *URL* and *After*.  Then use the code you have used before to create the hyperlink as a `Chunk` and combine the 3 parts in a `Paragraph`:

```
Chunk before = new Chunk("Before ");
Chunk c = new Chunk("www.google.com");
Chunk after = new Chunk(" After");
// create link annotation for c
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(before);
p.add(c);
p.add(after);
```

If you want to handle multiple hyperlinks within 1 paragraph, simply do the same thing again for the *After* text.

For testing, you may want to disable automatic hyperlinking in your PDF viewer, so you can check the link annotation is really there.  In Adobe Acrobat you can do this in the general preferences pane: uncheck "Create links from URLs".